# Youtube watch all unseen later (javascript)

Tags: javascript, youtube

I've started making scripts for things I do regularly to make my internet usage run more smoothly (and to learn javascript). One of those things is to add all unseen videos in my YouTube subscription box to the watch later list. I've written this in a bookmark:

```
javascript: 
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("contains-addto ");
for (var k = x.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    if (!x[k].classList.contains("watched")) {
        x[k].getElementsByClassName("addto-watch-later-button")[0].click();
    }
}
```

and it kind of works, except it simply doesn't add all unwatched. It seems a bit random which videos are added and which aren't.

Is there some kind of error? Or is there maybe a better way than looping through the thumbnail objects?

EDIT: Ok, not completely random. It seems to add the oldest two and the newest one in that (correct) order. If I reload the subscriptions page and press the bookmark again, it will add the next two from the bottom and the second newest and so on...

Comment: if you remove the `if (!x[k].classList.contains("watched")) {` statement it seems to work well enough

Comment: But then it would add all videos, not only unwatched, right? Is there a better way to figure out which are watched and which aren't?

Comment: I see that some of the behavior of the button is dynamic, especially adding and removing CSS classes, thus I don't know what is the right way. What triggers a watched class anyway? Experiment with [selectorgadget](http://selectorgadget.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a timeout, so that YouTube doesn't skip over requests:

```js
javascript:
  (function() {
    let unwatchedVideos = document.querySelectorAll('.contains-addto:not(.watched)');
    let i = unwatchedVideos.length;
    let int = setInterval(function() {
      if (--i >= 0) {
        unwatchedVideos[i].querySelector('.addto-watch-later-button').click();
      } else {
        clearInterval(int);
      }
    }, 300);
  })();
```

Comment: Yes. This actually seems to solve the problem. I haven't been watching Youtube like this for over a year, but it feels good to know there's a solution.
What do you mean by "half-subscriptions"?